# Print terminal in browser?

Tags: linux

I have counter-strike servers and i want to print server terminal console in web page.
I imagine all that like i have form with input field with content for ip and port of server when i type ip and port for the server i redirected to new page with server console.

Maybe we need the pid of process and i know this:
netstat -tunap | grep 62.213.181.39:27016

When i type this in terminal i get pid of process with this ip.

My questions is how to do that?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: `some-comand | tee /var/www/server-output.txt`

Comment: I need to show terminal in real time. (like flash/java or something else)

Comment: there are several options: 1) load that file in an iframe and use javascript to reload it from time to time. 2) write a PHP script to "tail" that file and keep reloading. 3) write a script to stream the file to the browser. Unfortunately my pomodoro break is off and I lack the time to post a complete solution.